# PHP Laravel Pagination: Method links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Hi I'm trying to setup pagination for a simple comments page.

I'm getting the error *Method links does not exist.*

Is it due to the comments being referenced from it's relationship to the post class?

Can't work out what to do here...

**CommentController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $comments = Comment::find($id)->paginate(5);
    return view('posts.show')->with('comments', $comments);
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
    <li>
        User Name: {{ $comment->user_name }} <br>
        Comment: {{ $comment->comment }} <br>
    </li><br>
@endforeach

{{ $post->comments->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

**find()** function find only one record and paginate workes with query builder or an Eloquent query, so you can use

```
$comments= Comment::where('post_id', $id)->paginate(5);
```

and replace **$post->comments** to **$comments**, it should be

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <li>
        User Name: {{$comment->user_name}} <br>
        Comment: {{$comment->comment}} <br>
    </li><br>
@endforeach
{{$comments->links()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method you are paginating `$comments` but use `$post->comments` in your view. Replace your code with:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <li>
        User Name: {{$comment->user_name}} <br>
        Comment: {{$comment->comment}} <br>
    </li><br>
@endforeach
{{$comments->links()}}
```

Comment: No, I need to use the $post->comments as it's referencing comments from a CommentController that is being referenced from a PostController. ie. It needs to go to the $post first to be able to find comments

Answer (score 0):

create the pagination links using the render method:

```
@foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
    <li>
        User Name: {{$comment->user_name}} <br>
        Comment: {{$comment->comment}} <br>
    </li><br>
    @endforeach
    {!! $comments->render() !!}
```